# Results of PIVOT in 0/1 true/false or other binary format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a pivot query which returns how much each customer has spent per category returning following result:

```
transaction_id  1       2       3       4       5       6       7
10-52927        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52928        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52929        8       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    149     NULL
10-52930        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52931        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52932        NULL    NULL    12      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52934        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10-52935        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    33      NULL
10-52936        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Pivot is based on multiple lines aggregating sales from product level to categories, meaning that each transaction_id record is aggregated from typically 20+ lines using sum() as pivot parameter.

What I would like to achieve is to get results in 0-1 format indicating whether customer has purchased anything from category 1,2,3,4,5... ~400 without creating extra tables since the operation has to be repeated for 100+ stores.

Any suggestion how to perform this task without creating additional tables to store and update results?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The query producting presented output is following:

```
select transaction_id, [1], [2], [3], // up to ~400 numerical categories
from (SELECT  [transaction_id]
             ,[category]
             ,sum([SUM]) as SUM_2
      FROM [XXX].[dbo].[receipts]
      left join // join of recept table with category table
      where // store type related parametrs
      group by transaction_id, category) p 
PIVOT (sum([sum_2]) for [category] in
       ([1], [2], [3], [4], ... ) // shortened list of categories in order to improve code readability
      ) as pvt 
ORDER BY pvt.transaction_id
```

categories

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your table structure?

Comment: and your existing query...

Answer (score 0):

OK you can do this without changing you cte (the FROM part).

In between SELECT and FROM add

```
INTO #MyTempTable
```

Safer is creating this before hand, checking to see if it already exists, and INSERTing from your existing SELECT.

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT transaction_id, CASE WHEN [1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [1], 
-- repeat each case
FROM #MyTempTable
```

If you can changed your CTE, remove the group by and the aggregate [SUM_v2], and just give it a value of 1 always.  In the PIVOT change SUM to MIN

Then the columns from the table can be checked in a more simple fashion: `ISNULL([1], 0) [1]`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty fun question.  This is a second solution where I get a cross product of the group and spreading column IDs so that there is always a value.  I can imagine there is a performance penalty associated with this method.

I used @Mark Bannister's use of SIGN to produce the 1 in the 0/1 column.

```
;WITH P AS
(
   SELECT 
      IDS.transaction_id, IDS.category, CAST(ISNULL(SIGN(C.Sum), 0) AS INT) [hassum]
   FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT
      A.transaction_id, B.category
      FROM Reciepts [A] CROSS JOIN Categories [B]) AS IDS
      LEFT JOIN Transaction AS T ON T.transaction_id = IDS.transaction_ID
      LEFT JOIN Category AS C ON -- some unspecified join ...
          AND C.Category = IDS.Category
)
SELECT transaction_id, [1], [2], [3]
FROM P
PIVOT (MIN(hassum) FOR category IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) AS [hassum]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can group your source table so there will be 0 or 1 matching row, then using COUNT(Category) should work. (It works in my similar but slightly different scenario)